# Do international students need to take the SAT and TOEFL to study in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, exams, international-students, language-exams, toefl

I am from Colombia and would like to do grad school in the United States.

It seems in order to study I need to take the SAT and TOEFL exams? Is this correct or does it depend on the university?

Comment: I would recommend you to take the IELST instead of  TOEFL. The TOEFL is not accepted in the UK for visa purposes and IELTS is accepted by both countries, in the UK and US.

Answer (score 11):

No, you don't need to take the [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT).  The SAT is for students going into undergrad.  Instead, you'll probably need to take the [GRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Record_Examinations), which is a similar exam for students going into grad school.

Yes, you'll *probably* need to do the [TOEFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOEFL), I'd guess.  That seems like a common requirement for international students.

Both of these requirements vary from institution to institution, so you'll probably want to check with the specific institutions that you want to apply to.  Depending on the program you want to go into, you may even have to take a [GRE subject test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Record_Examinations#GRE_Subject_Tests).

Answer (score 1):

Either GRE or IELTS test has to be taken before applying for any university, After that based on your grades/points, they will offer you admission. Beside this, you should get a study visa however it is a different story